# Why tableview.visibleCells is empty?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can it happens that an obviously visible and full width content tableview  has no visible cell?
Why is tableview.visibleCells empty?

Comment: you'll need to add more details to it. without context no one can help you. Add some code, or screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be to say that you are calling this method before the tableview had a chance to populate itself.

Make sure you've call that after the delegate method are called and after the tableview is on screen.

For a more accurate answer we will need to have more details about your problem.

Comment: Is there a method or event that will call/be fired once the tableview is populated?

Comment: @Chucky, look at the UITableViewDelegate's methods, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm retrieving calendar event data for a UICollectionView using an restful async method. I then want to scroll to the today's date, but visible cells is always zero when I try to do this in ViewDidLoad, SubviewsDidLoad, etc. I'm not sure which Delegate method would be appropriate here.

Comment: CellDisplayingEnded seems to be the closest method but this isn't called on the initial loading of cells, only thereafter from scrolling, maybe other interactions also

Comment: table view will be updated only when it is displayed, so before viewDidAppear I would not expect visible cell to be reliable